# Como numerar linhas de um data.frame no R?

Tags: r, data.frame

Supondo que tenho o seguinte data.frame:

```
print(DADOS)

letra N1 N2 N3 N4
A     2  3  4  4
A     1  2  3  4
A     2  2  1  3
B     0  1  2  0 
C     4  4  3  2
C     2  2  2  2
D     4  3  2  1
D     1  0  1  4
E     4  4  4  4
```

Como posso numerar as linhas do meu data.frame, deixando ele assim:

```
print(DADOS_numerados)

    letra N1 N2 N3 N4 numeracao
    A     2  3  4  4  1
    A     1  2  3  4  2
    A     2  2  1  3  3
    B     0  1  2  0  4
    C     4  4  3  2  5
    C     2  2  2  2  6
    D     4  3  2  1  7
    D     1  0  1  4  8
    E     4  4  4  4  9
```

Eu sei que parece uma coisa simples, mas tentei inúmeras maneiras sem sucesso.

Como posso enumerar cada linha do meu data.frame no R?

Comment: A melhor solução foi dada pelos @Carlos Eduardo no campo de respostas. De maneira bem arcaica, você pode saber o **1)** número de linhas: `nrow(df)` e depois **2)** criar um vetor no seu banco de dados. Supondo que o número de linhas seja `10`, então:  `df$numeracao <- 1:10`

Comment: obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras para executar esta ação. Deixo aqui uma contribuição com exemplos utilizando comandos do R "base" e com auxílio de pacotes.

- Com comandos residentes no R:

Como já mostrado por @CarlosEduardoLagosta, é interessante que um vetor seja previamente criado para que a operação seja mais fluida.

Para criar os vetores, para este caso/pergunta, tem-se a opção de uso do `nrow` ou `seq.int`.

```
numeracao <- 1:nrow(dados) # de 1 ate numero de linhas do data frame dados 
numeracao <- seq.int(nrow(dados))
# seq.int = sequencia de int de 1 ate numero de linhas do data frame dados
```

Feito isto, basta colar o vetor no *data frame* de interesse com `cbind` ou utilizando colchetes `[ ]` para criar uma nova coluna.

```
dados <- cbind(dados, numeracao)
dados[, "numeracao"] <- numeracao
```

- Com emprego de pacotes:

Esta operação também é comumente feita com auxílio de pacotes como o `dplyr` e `tibble`. É possível também criar previamente o vetor/coluna de interesse e depois proceder com a ação desejada, contudo creio que seja mais comum criar o vetor dentro da própria função do pacote, como este `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr)
dados <- dados %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(numeracao = 1:nrow(dados))
```

`bind_cols` tem a mesma função do `cbind`, mas seu emprego possibilita a criação de uma "grande" estrutura de função utilizando o `dplyr`.

```
dados <- dados %>% 
  dplyr::bind_cols(numeracao = 1:nrow(dados))
```

O pacote `tibble` tem uma função específica para criação desta `numeracao`/**id**, que é a função `rowid_to_column`. A função `rownames_to_column` também pode ser facilmente implementada e adaptada, mas vale ressaltar a importância de verificar se os nomes das linhas (*rownames*) são numéricos e estão na ordem correta.

```
library(tibble)
dados <- tibble::rowid_to_column(dados, var = "numeracao")
dados <- tibble::rownames_to_column(dados, var = "numercao")
```

E usando `dplyr` e `tibble` também é possível fazer isto facilmente.

```
dados <- dados %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "numercao")
```

*Obs.: O pipe (`%>%`) é um operador do pacote `magrittr` mas é comumente associado ao `dplyr`.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, vou testar.

Answer (score 4):

```
DADOS <- read.table(text = 
  'letra N1 N2 N3 N4
   A     2  3  4  4
   A     1  2  3  4
   A     2  2  1  3
   B     0  1  2  0 
   C     4  4  3  2
   C     2  2  2  2
   D     4  3  2  1
   D     1  0  1  4
   E     4  4  4  4',
  header = TRUE)

DADOS$numeracao <- 1:nrow(DADOS)

> head(DADOS)
  letra N1 N2 N3 N4 numeracao
1     A  2  3  4  4         1
2     A  1  2  3  4         2
3     A  2  2  1  3         3
4     B  0  1  2  0         4
5     C  4  4  3  2         5
6     C  2  2  2  2         6
```

Mas a não ser que use essa variável para alguma operação muito específica, ela é desnecessária; você pode simplesmente usar os números das linhas.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta vou testar

Comment: Ops, meu erro. Tinha usado tudo minúscula e esqueci de mudar tudo ao colar a resposta. Vou editá-la.

Answer (score 3):

Com o pacote `dplyr`, um modo simples é o seguinte.

```
dados <- dados %>% mutate(numeracao = row_number())

dados
#  letra N1 N2 N3 N4 numeracao
#1     A  2  3  4  4         1
#2     A  1  2  3  4         2
#3     A  2  2  1  3         3
#4     B  0  1  2  0         4
#5     C  4  4  3  2         5
#6     C  2  2  2  2         6
#7     D  4  3  2  1         7
#8     D  1  0  1  4         8
#9     E  4  4  4  4         9
```

Note que também pode ser

```
dados <- mutate(dados, numeracao = row_number())
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, vou testar.